# Excel - Add a single horizontal "target line" to the horizontal axis

Tags: excel, excel-charts

I have a X Y (Scatter) chart in Excel that is currently displaying two data sets exactly as I want them. Is it possible to add a single "target" line at a point of my choosing across the X access?

So let's say the Y axis is 0% up to 100%. let's say I am only ever happy if either line that I have plotted are below 50%. Is it possible to add a single red line, across 50%, so I can see at a glance when a line is on or below it?

Answer (score 1):

Following the scheme:

[image]

You can add a column for an *Additional* series.
In the cells:

```
C2 -> =$C$1
```

and autocomplete to have the value set in C1.
Add the Serie modify the source data
**Format of the Series:**

```
- Marker Options -> None
- Line Color -> Solid Line
- Remove from Legend the Serie Added
```

Eventually to enlarge the line, you can add a Trendline on this Series:

```
- Trendline Options -> Forecast -> 1 & 1
- Line Color -> Solid Line
```

Eventually Lock the DataSource Range:

```
- Format Axis -> Axis Option -> Minimun & maximum ...
```

[image]